# HAProxy - Large number of backend servers impacting start time

Tags: haproxy

Good morning,

I am running into a performance issue as the number of backend servers in my HAProxy configuration increases. This seems to only impact start time and validation time, not performance as it pertains to the proxy itself.

The startup/validation time is only about 1 second with ~1,000 backend servers. As this number increases to 50,000, I am noticing the startup/validation time take over 45 seconds.

I believe this issue has to do with HAProxy performing DNS resolution on all of these servers. As an experiment, I added 'init-addr none' to the defaults section and saw a slight increase in performance, but nothing notable. Is there a way to turn this feature off, or is there more performance tuning that can be done to help speed this up?

```
HA-Proxy version 1.7.5 2017/04/03
```

Here's what one of my backend configurations currently looks like.

```
backend foo-1234
  cookie FOO_1234 insert indirect nocache

  server foo-s-1234-0 server:port check cookie foo-s1234-0 init-addr none
  server foo-s-1234-1 server:port check cookie foo-s1234-1 init-addr none
  ..
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!